# find start from absolute line number

Tags: vba, ms-word

I like to select inside of a document an range via:

```
Set rng = ThisDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
```

so my question is: how can I find `Start:` if I know Absolute line number?

example: for absolute line number 152 (from the beginning of the word) how to count words till that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `GoTo` to find the `Start` of a line:

```
ThisDocument.GoTo(what:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToFirst, Count:=152).Start
```

That's counting characters not words though.

edit: If you want to count words, use it as the end of a range

```
ThisDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=ThisDocument.GoTo(what:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToFirst, Count:=152).Start).Words.Count
```

There might be a nicer way to do that though.

Comment: for the Which argument, could you use wdGoToAbsolute to take you to the actual line?

Comment: correct: characters, not words...let me see if it will go this (your solution).

Comment: @sous2817 I think it won't make a difference, since both `wdGoToAbsolute` and `wdGoToFirst` have the same value (1). To be honest, I thought it was specifying the location inside the object specified by `What` when I wrote it...

Comment: @arcadeprecinct , thanks! this is what I was looking for. It is working (for my case).